# How to convert decimal value stored in a string to integer in java?

Tags: java

how to convert the string to integer in java if the string is like String str=“1490.20"?

Comment: What have you tried? Please don't just expect the SO community to answer a request for code if you haven't put in any effort yourself.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a zero-effort requirements dump.

Answer (score 5):

Use `int i = (int) Double.parseDouble("1490.20");` to convert it to an integer, but to keep the decimal, just use `double d = Double.parseDouble("1490.20");`.

Comment: above solution is not working for me. Let me be very specific I am getting value "1490.20" into a string variable. And I have one integer value I want to compare both and find out which value is bigger.

Comment: This will return 1 if the string is bigger, 0 if they're equal, and -1 if the string is smaller. I will assume the integer value you have is called `i`. `Double.compare(Double.parseDouble("1490.20"), i);`

Comment: You shouldn't answer "gimme teh codez" questions like this, it only encourages them - plz see [answer].

Comment: Hello James, thanks for your reply. I tried above code, its working fine for value "539.10", but its showing error when the value is "1490.20". I am getting error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1,420.90""

Comment: Ah, you are using a comma, which isn't a number. To remove all non-numerical characters, from a string called s, say `s = s.replaceAll("[^0-9\\.]", "");`